# Is there a spectral sequence for Ext associated to an $n$-term exact sequence of modules?

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

I ask this question because of the following fact:

Let $R$ be a ring and $0 \to M_1 \to M_2 \to M_3 \xrightarrow{\alpha} M_4 \to 0$ be an exact sequence of $R$-modules. Suppose we know $Ext_R(M_1,R)$, $Ext_R(M_2,R)$, $Ext_R(M_3,R)$.

Then we can assemble the long exact sequences associated to the sequences 
$0 \to M_1 \to M_2 \to \ker \alpha \to 0\text{ and }0 \to \ker \alpha \to M_3 \xrightarrow{\alpha} M_4 \to 0$ to find $Ext^i_R(M_4,R)$.

Question:  Is there is a standard spectral sequence that outputs the associated graded of $Ext^i_R(M_4,R)$, or degenerates to something that outputs $assgrd(Ext^i_R(M_4,R))$.

I am pretty familiar with the Serre spectral sequence, so feel free to be heavy on spectral sequence notation.

Comment: Ext has two variables. What ext groups are you interested in?

Comment: If you are interested in the Ext groups with first argument equal to M4, then remove M4 from the exact sequence you have, replace it by zero, so that you get a complex whose homology is M4. Now one of the hyperExt spectral sequences does what you want. Resolve the complex you got à la Cartan-Eilenberg, etc. This is explained in the book by Cartan and Eilenberg and, probably, in Weibel's (and in EGA, I guess)

Comment: If you only know the Ext groups of $M_i$ for all $i\neq 4$ and the maps between them in the long exact sequence, you cannot recover the Ext groups of $M_4$. For instance if in the long exact sequence you get the exact sequence $0 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to Ext_n(M_4,X) \to  \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 0$, you cannot deduce what $Ext_n(M_4,X)$ is.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question.  This exact sequence that you wrote now says that the associated graded with respect to a certain filtration of $Ext_n(M_4,X)$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2$, so it is determined up to extension.  That is the most that I hope to get from any spectral sequence.  See for instance where I attack the extension problem for the trivial fibration in my Q&A or for the spectral sequence of $B \mathbb{Z}/4$ using the bockstein spectral sequence.You can certainly recover $Assgrd(Ext(M_4,X))$  from the LES's of the two short exact sequences I wrote down.

Comment: For an example of this in action, from the Koszul complex  $0 \to k[x,y] \xrightarrow{} k[x,y]^{\oplus 2} \to k[x,y] \xrightarrow{eval}  k \to 0$ we can find $Ext^2_{k[x,y]}(k,k)=k$ and 0 otherwise,  from the LES's of the broken up short exact sequences $0 \to k[x,y] \xrightarrow \to k[x,y]^{\oplus 2} \to \langle x, y \rangle$ and $ 0 \to \langle x, y \rangle \to k[x,y] \xrightarrow{eval} k \to 0$

Comment: What's the "associated graded" a module? (As far as I know such an object occurs when the module is filtered, but I can't see any filtration here.)

Comment: Sorry, I should say that this above is the associated graded with respect to a certain filtration.  For example in the example given by @A.G., there is the filtration $\mathbb{Z}/2 \subset Ext_n(M_4,X)$ and the associated graded with respect to this filtration is $\mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2$